# ServiceStack.Text CSV serialization of IEnumerable<object> ignores custom serialization functions

Tags: csv, serialization, servicestack, servicestack-text

Firstly, please forgive any rookie mistakes here - I'm not a regular poster I'm afraid.

Now on to the nitty gritty...

I am trying to use ServiceStack.Text to serialize objects to CSV. If I keep it simple, everything works as expected when serializing objects of a known type.

However I want to serialize many objects and I don't know the type at runtime so I am writing a reusable component where all data is treated as a `System.Object`. We already do this same routine for Json serialization without problems. But `CsvSerializer` appears to handle objects differently during serialization.

## Sample code

```
    public void TestIEnumerableObjectSerialization()
    {
        var data = GenerateSampleData();

        JsConfig<DateTime>.SerializeFn = 
            time => new DateTime(time.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        var csv = CsvSerializer.SerializeToCsv(data);
        Console.WriteLine(csv);

        Assert.Equal("DateTime\r\n"
            + "2017-06-14 00:00:00\r\n"
            + "2017-01-31 01:23:45\r\n",
            csv);
    }

    object[] GenerateSampleData()
    {
        return new object[] {
            new POCO
            {
                DateTime = new DateTime(2017,6,14)
            },
            new POCO
            {
                DateTime = new DateTime(2017,1,31, 01, 23, 45)
            }
         };
    }

    public class POCO
    {
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    }
```

The result of this code is that the custom serialization function is not invoked, and the DateTime is written out using the standard `ToString()` method.

## The cause?

The `CsvWriter.Write` method is inspecting the type of the records and if the type is `Object` it is treated as a `Dictionary<string, object>` and `CsvDictionaryWriter` generates the output.

In turn, [`CsvDictionaryWriter`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/CsvWriter.cs#L23) uses the [`ToCsvField()`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/TextExtensions.cs#L33) extension method to write each property a record.

The problem is that `ToCsvField()` converts the value of each property to a string using `ToString()` meaning no custom serialization is performed.

`JsonSerializer` uses `TypeSerializer.SerializeToString(text)` to serialize the properties of an Object using any configured custom serialization functions; but this doesn't happen with `CsvSerializer`.

## A possible solution?

Without complicating `CsvSerializer`, the `ToCsvField()` extension method could be updated to use `TypeSerializer` to handle the serialization to a string. Here is what I've been testing with so far:

```
    public static object ToCsvField(this object text)
    {
        var textSerialized = TypeSerializer.SerializeToString(text).StripQuotes();
        return textSerialized == null || !CsvWriter.HasAnyEscapeChars(textSerialized)
            ? textSerialized
            : string.Concat
              (
                  CsvConfig.ItemDelimiterString,
                  textSerialized.Replace(CsvConfig.ItemDelimiterString, CsvConfig.EscapedItemDelimiterString),
                  CsvConfig.ItemDelimiterString
              );
    }
```

So far I haven't come across an issue with this change, although someone may prefer not to allocate a new intermediate variable before the return statement.

Hopefully that is enough information, so on to my questions...

1. Has anyone else experienced this issue?
2. Am I doing something wrong and should I be serializing Objects a different way?
3. If this is a suitable fix/implementation of TypeSerializer, what are the chances of this being addressed in an update to ServiceStack.Text? I would raise an issue on GitHub but the ServiceStack.Text repo doesn't let me raise issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mythz... Do you know how to run the NUnit tests for ServiceStack.Text? NUnit 3 Test Adapter extension in VS2017 fails to load the tests - possibly due to the new project format? Only test that appears in Test Explorer is a single test from ServiceStack.Text.Tests.xUnit.

Comment: You can use the R# NUnit Test runner, they have a [30 day free trial](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/). You can also run tests using the [NUnit Console Test Runner](https://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download) on **ServiceStack.Text.Tests.dll**

Comment: Cheers, merged this change is available from v4.5.13+ that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget)